# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am build an app with firebase dependencies before creating an app i have done the firebase configuration and added firebase dependencies in pubspec.yaml. But when i run the app i got some errors.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
  1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
  15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_auth' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@16.0.2
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_core' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.4
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_database' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@15.+

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: the problem also occur for me, does you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The Problem occur when the dependencies cannot download from jcenter server. **change your network connection** follows **flutter clean** and try again

you can still work in debug mode

**flutter run --debug** will work

or you can goto **File > Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle>Uncheck Offline work option** in Android Studio

You can also **invalidate Cache and Restart**